# #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)

Tags: c++, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{ count--;}
```

The above code is okay or not?

Comment: Is `count` an atomic type?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the code is not Ok. Race conditions are possible. You can use an atomic omp clause.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{ 
#pragma omp atomic update
    count--;
}
```

You can take a look into the spec about atomic https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu95.html

Comment: One could use atomic, but in this case it effectively makes a serial code out of a parallel program.  The case is a poor place to start from anyway.

Comment: There is a reduction clause for this.